# Design suggestions for Django Deployment

Tags: django, deployment, gunicorn

I have used Django on-and-off for the past year or so, but I have never deployed a website into a production environment.  I would love some input on my proposed deployment design.

**Use Case**

I will be deploying one- or two-page websites for multiple clients over the next several months.  I plan on either using a clienta.mysite.com or a mysite.com/clienta layout.  These pages will be forms that clients enter data into (such as credit card info), which will be transferred via SSL back to the server.  The server will then make the required connections to processing sites, process the transaction, and return the result to the client.

**Plan**

My plan is to use a Nginx + Gunicorn setup to handle the incoming connections and serve the simple pages.  In the future I will likely do some more complex page interaction, but for now they will be simple html forms.  The django backend will handle the interaction with the remote processing servers, and then return the results to the client through a generated results page.

**Questions**

- Will this implementation work for 10s or 100s of clients?
- Are there some obvious pitfalls I am not seeing?
- Is this overkill?  Are there simpler/better ways to handle this type of situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use one subdomain per client, you will require one SSL certificate per domain, or a wildcard certificate, which can be more expensive than a standard SSL certificate.

Comment: This is very good to know; I had completely forgotten about that effect of the subdomains.  mysite.com/clientA it is then.

Comment: Anyone else have some input on this?